# Query a result of another DataFrame query Spark

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe

Using spark and Pandas library for Python.
I basically have the following:

```
df.groupby('sIP').agg({'duration': 'sum'}).show()
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
+---------------+------------------+                                            
|            sIP|     sum(duration)|
+---------------+------------------+
| 203.13.173.243|               0.0|
|  204.62.16.153|         17522.927|
|  203.30.177.95|             1.081|
|   56.23.191.99|           113.186|
```

The sum of all the distinct source IP addresses duration.

What I want to do now is get the max from that sum, and get the associated source IP. So I would have to query the DataFrame after it got modified (the query above).

So I tried to:

```
df.groupby('sIP').agg({'duration': 'max'}).show()
```

But it still queries the original DataFrame, as follows:

```
+---------------+-------------+                                                 
|            sIP|max(duration)|
+---------------+-------------+
| 203.13.173.243|          0.0|
|  204.62.16.153|     1790.305|
|  203.30.177.95|        1.081|
|   56.23.191.99|       22.563|
```

Is there anyway to overwrite the dataframe state? I've looked at transformations but with no success, collect() was another thing I looked into but still nothing...

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your first transformation to a new dataframe, otherwise the result are simply discarded.

```
df1 = df.groupby('sIP').agg({'duration': 'max'}).toDF('sIP', 'max_duration')
```

Then you can operate on the new dataframe as you like, i.e.:

```
df1.sort('max_duration', ascending=False).show(1)
```

You can do both in one transformation without the intermediate dataframe anyway:

```
df.groupby('sIP').agg({'duration': 'max'}).sort('max(duration)', ascending=False).show(1)
```

Comment: I couldn't apply them togheter. But the first solution (separate) worked perfectly. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `sort_values` + `tail`

```
df.groupby('sIP').agg({'duration': 'sum'}).sort_values('sum(duration)').tail(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala

```
df.groupBy("ip").agg(sum("duration").as("sum_duration")).agg(max("sum_duration")).show()
```

PySpark

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy("ip").agg(F.sum("duration").alias("sum_duration")).agg(F.max("sum_duration")).show()
```